# Docker : Unable to find local grunt

Tags: angularjs, docker, docker-compose, gruntjs

I try to dockerise an old angularJS app but I hang at a problem. I have the impression that when docker dials up my volume it overwrites all that has been done previously.

My image is built successfully but when I run it I have this error:`Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.`

My goal is to be able to build my app while keeping the hot reload.

**Dockerfile :**

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:6 as builder

# Confirm versions
RUN node -v
RUN npm -v

# Add 
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
COPY bower.json /usr/src/app/bower.json
COPY Gruntfile.js /usr/src/app/Gruntfile.js
COPY .bowerrc /usr/src/app/.bowerrc

# Define app as root dir
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add app
#COPY . /usr/src/app

# Install sass & compass
RUN apk update && \
apk upgrade

RUN apk add --update \
ruby \
ruby-irb \
ruby-dev \
ruby-rdoc \
libffi-dev \
build-base

RUN gem install \
sass \
compass

# Install Perl
RUN apk add perl

# Install Git (rquired for angular dep)
RUN apk add git

# Install Yarn
RUN npm install -g yarn
RUN yarn -v

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install bower -g\
&& npm install -g grunt-cli \
&& yarn add grunt-contrib-imagemin \
&& yarn


# Build
RUN bower install --allow-root

EXPOSE 9000 35729

CMD [ "grunt", "--force" ,"server" ]
```

**docker-compose : **

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  app-dev:
    container_name: app-dev
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    volumes:
        - .:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - '9000:9000'
      - '35729:35729'
    restart: always
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you're running npm install on the docker image, which means that none of your packages from your package.json are going to present.

You should, in general, exclude node_modules from the docker build context with a .dockerignore, as you're going to want to rebuild your dependencies inside the container. A dependent module can, for instance, need to compile a native module for something. For instance, node-sass has a compiled component.